# Material Design Icons in LaTeX?

Tags: icon

If you are interested in mobile app or modern web development, you probably know Google's Material Design which also provides a lot of useful icons. You can find them [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/) or [here](https://materializecss.com/icons.html). Is there any easy way to use those icons in LaTeX? I could not find a package on CTAN for this.

It would be great if you could include them as vector graphics (not image files). I know, you can download `.svg` files and include the ones you want that way. But is there an even simpler solution?

I am also familiar with the `fontawesome` package which also provides you with a ton of nice icons but I think it's an advantage to be able to choose out of both - Material Design icons and fontawesome icons.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: they are apparently available in truetype font form MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf  so you could use that font directly in xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: That sounds great! I will take a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: Using LuaLaTeX I get errors with the `worldflags` package. XeLaTeX gives me errors with the `worldflags` and the `fontawesome` package which means I can not combine fontawesome and Material Design icons. I am not really that familiar with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Am I doing something wrong or should I consider other solutions?

Comment: One of the LuaLaTeX worldflags errors: `Missing $ inserted. \EndFlagDescription` - One of the XeLaTeX Fontawesome errors: `Package fontspec Error: The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.` and on of the XeLaTeX wordflags error: `Missing $ inserted. \EndFlagDescription`. In the worldflags package, I get this error when I use the Spain flag with the command `\worldflag{ES}`. Only a few flags have been tested.

Comment: don't ask new questions in comments, it makes the page hard to read for later readers. If you have an error with fontawesaome make a real small examople that reproduces the problem and ask a new question with teh example document and the exact error you get from the log file, in code blocks so line endings preserverd

Comment: Is it actually possible to use the truetype Material Design Icon font with lualatex? Large codepoints do not seem to work at all. For instance, I am trying to use codepoint U+F1372 that should be an "account" symbol and I am getting something completely different in the lualatex output. I am using either {\MDI \char"F1372} or {\MDI \char988018} where \MDI comes from a  \newfontface\MDI{Material Design Icons}[] . In no case I am getting the right char, but there seems to be no issue with the log file.